# Malware for testing

Tags: threat-mitigation, threat-modeling, threats

IS there websites and places where you can download all types of malware that you can run and test the security setup of your system?

I am currently playing around with UAC+EMET4+MSE and would like to see how well the system responds to different types of threats.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about all types of malwares but http://contagiodump.blogspot.in/ is a good place to start . Also you can get samples from malware.lu and virushare.com .

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html

EICAR test virus file.  This will help you test anti-malware applications.